# Can i install ubuntu14.04 on my system?

Tags: system-installation

my computer has 2gb ram and
[image]

is it possible to install ubuntu trusty tahr on my system
and will it run smootly on my system

Answer (score 1):

With only 2GB of RAM I'd suggest getting the 32-bit build of Ubuntu. Otherwise, 4GB of RAM is pretty much the recommended minimum for any modern 64-bit OS (like Ubuntu -- or dare I say it, Win___s).

FYI, Without 4GB of RAM or more and a 64-bit OS, it's rather like having Conestoga wagon wheels on your muscle car (like a Mustang or Camero). Sure, it'll (barely) work. But you'll always be wondering if there isn't something more you could do to get better performance.

...Of course, graphics is an entirely different subject but one worth mentioning. Cause having good graphics can be very much like the gas you put in your road beast.

Comment: Good and detailed answer, but it's worth noting that I run the 64-bit version with only 2 GB of RAM, and have had absolutely no performance issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your RAM is a tad on the low side but I expect it will run ok.  Try a live boot from CD or USB and see if it runs smoothly; if so, it will run better when fully installed.

If it is too slow, then try Xubuntu or Lubuntu, or better yet just stick with Ubuntu 12.04 as it still has several years of support left.  Honestly 14.04 isn't that much different than 12.04, so you will not be gaining much by pushing your system to run the newest releases.

You might want to wait a few weeks (or months) for all the bugs in 14.04 to be worked out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will install and run just fine, barring any other issues such as a weird graphics device. I've run Ubuntu on far, far less powerful computers.